# Node.js does not response change in html, js and css file in Ionic Project

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ionic-framework

After installing Ionic and cordova on node.js v6 , it doesn't respond on change in html, js and css file in Ionic framework.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: We need more information here. Did it respond to changes before? How are you watching for changes?

Comment: It respond 1st time when I made the change on file. After that there is no response.